# How to create a CI/CD pipeline for deployment on physical server

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have multiple servers installed at client site. I can access all of them via `anydesk`. I have python project running on them. All of the source code is in azure devops. I want to create a CI CD pipeline so that whenever we merge pull request to `main` branch, it should automatically be deployed on client's server.

Previously, I have worked on many `web API's` which was deployed on `azure`. We had branches created for each client and whenever we merge changes into those clients branch, it automatically used to start deployment on API as our repo and branch was linked to web API.

To deploy the new code changes on server, I have to follow manual way of first logging into the client server via anydesk and then perform the git pull to pull the required changes. This is very manual thing and we sometime do mistake in it. I am looking for a way to connect the client server with the branch of the repo so that once we merge our changes to that branch, it should automatically deploy the changes. Is there any way we can do it? Is there any tool/service available for this. All the client server are Ubuntu machines. Please give some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: This question is very broad. If you're familiar with CI/CD in general then the specific azure-devops feature you're looking for are Deployment Groups. See here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops.

Comment: To reduce the breadth, could you narrow down what you already have? Do you have a build pipeline? Does it have a trigger from the main branch? Do you have a release pipeline? Does it trigger when the build pipeline completes? Are you using classic or YAML pipelines? etc.

Comment: @Adam As of now I do not have anything setup. I just have repo where all the source code is present. I do not have any pipeline setup for deployment on clients physical server